Low Pressure Light Heat Pump
I have a GeoCool water-sourced heat pump with a low pressure issue. Every day, around the same time, the unit throws a low pressure light and we lose cooling. Not ideal since we are experience record highs in the 105+ range. Our HVAC tech checked the condenser, refrigerant, the filter, and the usual culprits but found no issues with those. He suggested that it might have something to do with the size of the duct work exiting the unit and flowing back into the vents. Apparently, the size of the ductwork exiting the unit isn't big enough (it's 1000cf) for the power of the unit (rated at 2000cf). He thinks that might be triggering a low pressure warning. I am having a hard time understanding this logic and am hoping someone could verify that information as a possible cause.

Have you tried slowing the air handler fan down? (There should be some way to do it, documented in the air handler's manual and wiring diagram)

Is the water source from a geothermal/ground loop dedicated to you, or a building/district loop? Is it possible that it's referring to low water pressure? Can you find out more about what the 'low pressure' light means, or the exact model so we can get a service manual?

My first thought was the same as ThreePhaseEel's. Most forced air heat/cool furnaces use a higher fan setting for AC than for heat and move more air. It may be possible to test your tech's theory by slowing the fan down to the same setting as for heat. It usually means changing some wiring to a different stab on the motor so the tech should probably do this.
